# Unable to find specified file. is there anything wrong in this powershell script?

Tags: powershell

I am new to Powershell and my intention is to write a message to an output file if an input file doesn't exist in a directory. I have written this following code after digging into most of the documents available on internet.

```
function isDailyCommSummaryExists()
{
    param ($content)
    if(-Not([System.IO.File]::Exists("$filePath\DailyCommSummary.mai")))
    {
        $content | Out-File -FilePath "$filePath\test.txt" -Encoding ascii 
    }
    else
    {
        $content | Out-File -FilePath "$filePath\test.txt" -Encoding ascii -Append
    }
}
```

**$content** is the value that needs to be written into file.

**$filePath** is something like **C:\MyFolder\**
But I'm getting "Unable to find the specified file"
[image]

I don't think the usage of Out-File is wrong here. Please correct me if it is wrong.

Comment: It is incomplete. 1. You are using 2 variables `$content` and `$filepath` but not defining it's values. 2. You have written a function but told it to use no input by using `()`and asking for an input using the `param($content)` line. Remove the first `()`.  3. Also, you are not calling the function after defining it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
function isDailyCommSummaryExists
{
    param (
        $content
    )

    $filePath = "C:\MyFolder"

    if(-Not([System.IO.File]::Exists("$filePath\DailyCommSummary.mai")))
    {
        $content | Out-File -FilePath "$filePath\test.txt" -Encoding ascii 
    }
    else
    {
        $content | Out-File -FilePath "$filePath\test.txt" -Encoding ascii -Append
    }
}
isDailyCommSummaryExists -content "<put content in here>"
```

However, this is all you need.

```
function isDailyCommSummaryExists
    {
        param (
            $content
        )

        $filePath = "C:\MyFolder"
        if(-Not([System.IO.File]::Exists("$filePath\DailyCommSummary.mai")))
        {
            $content | Out-File -FilePath "$filePath\test.txt" -Encoding ascii -Append
        }
    }
    isDailyCommSummaryExists -content "<put content in here>"
```

`Out-file` with `-append` will create the file if it doesn't exist and append if it does.

Comment: thank you @Rohin Sidharth, but when I have already tried your suggestion and encounter error as "Unable to find the specified file." I updated question with output screenshot for reference.

Comment: @shary.sharath Indicates that the path isn't correct. Have you tried with the absolute path of the file instead of using a variable?

Comment: What do u get when you run this? `test-path "C:\MyFolder\DailyCommSummary.mai"`

Comment: it is coming false, yet not creating file.

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote your code to test it by adding the filepath as a parameter, but I'm not sure it's set up to do what you intend it to:

```
function isDailyCommSummaryExists()
{
  param ($content,$filePath)
  if(-Not([System.IO.File]::Exists("$filePath\DailyCommSummary.mai")))
  {
    $content | Out-File -FilePath "$filePath\test.txt" -Encoding ascii
  }
  else
  {
    $content | Out-File -FilePath "$filePath\test.txt" -Encoding ascii -Append
  }
}

isDailyCommSummaryExists -content "hello" -filePath "c:\temp"
```

This will look for a file called DailyCommSummary.mai, and if it's not there will output "hello" to test.txt. If DailyCommSummary.mai does exist, it will append content to DailyCommSummary.mai.

Is that the behaviour you intended?

Do you mean to have "$filePath\DailyCommSummary.mai" as the destinations in the out-File? If so a simple Out-File with the -append parameter would suffice.

Edit: Based on the comments, I believe the problem is that there are wildcard characters in your path, so this should work:

```
function isDailyCommSummaryExists()
{
  param ($content,$filePath)
  if(-Not([System.IO.File]::Exists("$filePath\DailyCommSummary.mai")))
  {
    $content | Out-File -LiteralPath "$filePath\test.txt" -Encoding ascii
  }
  else
  {
    $content | Out-File -LiteralPath "$filePath\test.txt" -Encoding ascii -Append
  }
}

isDailyCommSummaryExists -content "hello" -filePath "C:\temp\AppData[CSRExtractQueue]\"
```

Comment: yes, it is. But Out-File is not working for me. It is saying  "unable to find specified file." I am clueless why is it happening. If I do Test-Path for the same file, it is false. It means, file doesn't exist so it should create a file at least. but not creating.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this error. What are you passing in for the $filepath variable? Could there be some unusual characters in the path that's causing the error?

Comment: There is no any special characters in path. I am passing "F:\AppData\[CSRExtractQueue]\" for this path Test-Path is not able to verify the existing file. So I tried using [System.IO.File]::Exists(<file path>) and it worked. But while using Out-File nothing seems to be working.

Comment: Are there actually square brackets in the path (as these are likely to be interpreted as search characters) or are you using them to demonstrate a variable here?

Comment: Hey @Dicky Moore, you are right. It was due to that square bracket in directory name. But now challenge is to escape that while searching or using Out-File. any idea?

Comment: You can use LiteralPath instead of FilePath